# Methods to link common class attributes between objects? (not inheritance)

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, attributes

I have a number of objects of the same class, each holding different data.

However, they have a number of attributes that should be 'common' - i.e. set to the same value across all objects. (this could be a numeric value, a reference to another object etc etc)

What are different methods of implementing this?
A couple of methods I thought of:

A dictionary containing all the objects and the common attributes as separate key/value pairs. The problem here is that the objects are dynamically created (there is a variable number of objects read from file) so creating keys could be a problem

A 'collection' class, where the common attributes are defined in this collection class and the group of objects is passed in as a list

I can't help feeling that there might be alternatives out there, or 'better' methods (I know that is subjective, but I'd like to know all possibilities...)

**Edit:**.

Here is my specific example.

I have a number of objects, each defining the branch of a river (from now on called `Branches`. So, they all have different x,y point attributes.

They should all be 'linked' to another object, in this case an object describing the elevation over the domain (from now on called `DEM`)

One way to do it could be a 'collector' class (call it `Network`) which groups together all the `Branches` objects and has an attribute which is a reference to the DEM.

This way, I can safely use the `DEM` in all calculations using `Branches`. However, it is not ideal. I would like each `Branches` object to have a method which returns the elevation at each point. For that, `DEM` needs to either be passed into the `Branches` method (meaning I cannot define that method as a property, which I would like to do) or there needs to be an attribute within each `Branches` object pointing to `DEM`. The second method runs the risk of allowing separate instances of `DEM` to be referenced within each `Branches` object, which I don't won't to allow. It also seems a bit silly to have each `Branches` object holding a separate reference to the same thing (1 global reference would be preferred - this way I can change it without having to go through each `Branches` object).

I find this kind of thing cropping up all over - I have a load of instances of the same object, but I want to keep some attributes common between them - so more general answers are preferred..

Comment: Your case is a bit too abstract. Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have attributes that are shared by and accessible to all instances of a class, use class attributes:

```
class MyClass(object):

    myclassattr = 0 # class attribute

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.myinstattr = attr # instance attribute
        if MyClass.myclassattr == 0:
            print("First!")
        MyClass.myclassattr += 1
```

For example:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
First!
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> MyClass.myclassattr
2
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Suppose you wanted to change the class attribute between all instances - is it just a case of pointing it to something else, or do you need to define a method to handle this? E.g. I create a pair of objects, and `myclassattr` is 0. Now I want to change it to 1 for both objects

Comment: You should note that I already change the class attribute, for all instances, in my example. If you already had `a` and `b` and wanted to reset `MyClass.myclassattr`, you could do it within an instance method, a class method, or externally, by accessing `MyClass.myclassattr` (except in class method, where it would be `cls.myclassattr`).

Comment: I just came across a new problem. Lets say I want to have 2 groups of this object, the first group needs `myclassattr` = 0 and the second group needs `myclassattr` = 1. Changing `myclassattr` to 1 for the second group will change the first...is there a way around?

Comment: No, the whole point of class attributes is that they are shared by *all* instances. Having read your edited question, I think you need to define what you call a collection object. To get around the worry about multiple DEMs, when you add to the collection: `def add_branch(branch): branch.dem = self.dem; self.branches.append(branch)` this gives each branch a reference to the collection's dem.

Comment: Hmm. The problem with the above is if I then want to change the reference to `DEM` I will need a function iterating through all branches. I'd rather avoid that overhead if possible...

Comment: Alternatively, process the branches through a collection instance method; make the dem an argument to the branch instance methods. E.g. `def process_branches(self): for branch in self.branches: branch.process(self.dem)`.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is a superclass which defines the DEM and branches. Then on the branch methods that need the DEM but I would also like to be properties, I can call `parent.dem` and avoid having to pass the dem into the method (so it can still be a property)?

Comment: No, a superclass won't work here; your problem is composition, not inheritance ("has a" not "is a").

Comment: yes I just realised after I posted. I would like to decorate the `branch.process` method however...I can 'manually' decorate to be able to accept arguments, but if I can avoid such complications...

Comment: Perhaps you should create a new question for this specific need (after searching for any already existing, of course!)